# port forward with openVPN to access local machine remotely

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have an OpenVPN server set up on my AWS Linux instance and I can successfully use the OpenVPN client to connect to the server using an `.ovpn` configuration file. My question is how can I set up port forwarding to access web servers hosted on my local machine using `myAwsPublicIp:openedPort` without having to set up forwarding rules on my router. I already tried opening the port on my AWS firewall rules but that didn't do it. How does portmap.io achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736687/port-forward-with-openvpn-to-access-local-machine-remotely) to multiple sites.

Comment: You need to set up firewall rules on your vpn server. dnat  the `external_IP:port` of your VPN server to your vpn client

Comment: You could use [AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn/), which is quite easy. Just remember it's charged for 24/7. I used to reduce the cost to zero by removing the Client VPN attachments using a script, putting them back when I needed it to be available. Typically these days I use AWS Session Manager instead of VPN.